# Is there a way in teradata to replace mutiple string in a row from another table?

Tags: teradata

I Have two tables `Customer` and `Road_AB`

Customer table data:

```
id Add
1  India NW
2  Poland NW HV
3  ASIA HV
```

Road_AB data:

```
text abb
NW   NEW
HV   Heaven
```

My requirement is perform update on `Customer` table from `Road_AB`.
There can be multiple strings in a row that needs to be updated.

Expected Result after update:

`Customer` table data:

```
id Add
1  India NEW
2  Poland NEW Heaven
3  ASIA Heaven
```

Answer (score 1):

The tricky part here is that you are going to have to join on an arbitrary subtring of a column to your `Road_ab` table which is no doubt causing all sorts of head scratching. Thankfully Teradata has this awesome `strtok_split_to_table` function that will allow you to split a column in a record into MULTIPLE records on a delimiter. So we can split `India NW` into two records `India` and `NW` splitting on a space  character. Then we can join and use `XMLAGG()` to join those split strings back together. Those functions allow us to preserve order and record keys throughout the process as well.

Here is a working example using your sample data:

```
CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE Customer(
   id  INTEGER  
  ,Addf VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
INSERT INTO Customer(id,Addf) VALUES (1,'India NW');
INSERT INTO Customer(id,Addf) VALUES (2,'Poland NW HV');
INSERT INTO Customer(id,Addf) VALUES (3,'ASIA HV');

CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE Road_AB(
   textf CHAR(2)  
  ,abb  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
INSERT INTO Road_AB(textf,abb) VALUES ('NW','NEW');
INSERT INTO Road_AB(textf,abb) VALUES ('HV','Heaven');

SELECT splitCustomer."id",  TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM (XMLAGG(TRIM(COALESCE(road_ab.abb, splitCustomer.token))|| '' ORDER BY splitCustomer.TokenNum) (VARCHAR(10000), CHARACTER SET UNICODE)))
FROM 
    (
        SELECT * 
        FROM TABLE (STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(customer.id, customer.addf, ' ')
         RETURNS (id integer 
         ,tokennum INTEGER
         ,token VARCHAR(30) CHARACTER SET UNICODE)
         ) AS dt
    ) splitCustomer
    LEFT OUTER JOIN road_ab
        ON trim(splitCustomer.token) = trim(road_ab.textf)
GROUP BY 1;

DROP TABLE customer;
DROP TABLE Road_ab;


+----+-------------------+
| id |        add        |
+----+-------------------+
|  3 | ASIA Heaven       |
|  2 | Poland NEW Heaven |
|  1 | India NEW         |
+----+-------------------+
```

It's worth noting that if you have huge data, this won't be fast. Your indexing isn't going to help here since we have to generate an interim result set that is going to be many times larger than the source data, join that to your `road_ab` table, and then go through the pain of string aggregation.

It's also worth noting that this may fail if your `Add` column in `Customer` isn't sized appropriately. It looks like you are replacing smaller words with larger words and if those blow over the size of the column then your INSERT based on this SELECT is going to fail.

Comment: Thank you @JNevill for the solution. I tried this solution but I got an error for outer select. Its giving me error "Error Code 6706: The string contains an untranslatable character."

Comment: I assume then you have a unicode column here. I have updated that XMLAGG to handle unicode.